# discord.js Cant use command with user ID

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm making a command that rickrolls the mentioned user by sending them a dm and when i try to use it by mentioning someone using their ID it dosent work and sends the error message i added saying: `The mentioned user is not in the server`

```
const { DiscordAPIError } = require('discord.js');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const BaseCommand = require('../../utils/structures/BaseCommand');

module.exports = class RickrollCommand extends BaseCommand {
  constructor() {
    super('rickroll', 'fun', []);
  }

  async run(client, message, args) {
    let mentionedMember = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
    if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send('You need to mention a member to rickroll.');
    if (!mentionedMember) return message.channel.send('The user mentioned is not in the server.');
    if (mentionedMember.user.id == client.user.id) return message.channel.send('You really thought i was boutta rickroll myself? AINT NO WAY CHEIF');

    const rickrollEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("You've Been Rickrolled!")
    .setThumbnail('https://i1.wp.com/my-thai.org/wp-content/uploads/rick-astley.png?resize=984%2C675&ssl=1')
    .setDescription('Rick astley sends his regards')
    .setColor('#FFA500');

    await mentionedMember.send('https://tenor.com/view/dance-moves-dancing-singer-groovy-gif-17029825')
    await mentionedMember.send(rickrollEmbed)
    .then(() => {
      message.channel.send("Successfully rickrolled the user.");
   })
    .catch(err => {
      message.channel.send('I was unable to rickroll the user.');
    });
  }
}
```

The wierd part is it only works with my ID and not any other user's ID.

Comment: I think the problem is, that when using the user ID, you can't retrieve the user with the mentions and so it tries to get it from the cache, but the only user in cache is yours. Therefore it will not find any other users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is, that you are using the cache and not the guilds member manager. Therefore, when no other user is cached it will only work with your ID since you are the one sending the message => getting loaded into the cache.

Try this:

```js
async run(client, message, args) {
  let mentionedMember = message.mentions.members.first() || await message.guild.members.fetch(args[0]);
  if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send('You need to mention a member to rickroll.');
  if (!mentionedMember) return message.channel.send('The user mentioned is not in the server.');

  ...
}
```

I don't know for sure, but it might also be a bit more optimized if you still prefer the cache, but just use the member manager as an additional backup, like this:

```js
async run(client, message, args) {
  let mentionedMember = message.mentions.members.first()
    || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])
    || await message.guild.members.fetch(args[0]);
  if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send('You need to mention a member to rickroll.');
  if (!mentionedMember) return message.channel.send('The user mentioned is not in the server.');

  ...
}
```